# Prestashop Symfony serializer on Front Office

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, prestashop

I'm developing a module for PrestaShop that is getting data from external API and showing it on the front & back offices.

I'm trying to use symfony serializer component to deserialize API response into PHP objects, everything works when you're calling a service from a back office, however things are not working on the front office (that is using legacy system).

Simple example of services.yml file of my module

```
  my_company.my_service:
    class: ModuleNamespace\MyService
    arguments:
      - '@serializer'
```

The error i'm getting on the front office is

```
The service "my_company.my_service" has a dependency on a non-existent service "serializer".
```

Seems like that lightweight Symfony container for Legacy environment (PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Adapter\ContainerBuilder) is not loading that symfony component.

How to properly prepare my config files to make sure that symfony serializer component is available within Legacy environment?

There is another way to make it is to initialize Serializer class within MyService class manually (this way its not autoloading custom normalizers that i've defined too), however i would like to do dependency injection with all it benefits.

Comment: The frontend container is very lightweight and does not include any bundle not symfony services like the serializer. You can still create your own, you can follow Symfony documentation to do that.

Comment: I've decided to use cuyz/valinor package instead of trying to get symfony serializer work

Comment: We plan to support Symfony container in front office in PrestaShop 9. It's not "that" easy to do, there's work in progress :)